# Check installed packages on Mac OS X and install new ones

Tags: packages, errors, installing, mac

When trying to compile a new LaTeX document, this line

```
\usepackage[mtplusscr,mtbold]{mathtime}
```

produces the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 <
     !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
```

although the first lines are

```
\documentclass{IOS-Book-Article}
% 
\usepackage{times}
\normalfont
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[mtplusscr,mtbold]{mathtime}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}                           % The preamble begins here.
```

If I remove the mentioned line, everything compiles without problem although not with the desired output.

I am new to LaTeX on the Mac. I guess the error has to do with the package [mtplusscr,mtbold]{mathtime} which is not installed. I therefore wonder how can I check whether a package is installed on a Mac and then how can I install it?

Comment: You can see the packages installed using the Tex Live Utility (assuming you installed TeX using Texlive)

Comment: Is `IOS-Book-Article` a class you wrote yourself? Sounds interesting!

Comment: no, it is not a class I wrote myself, is a template from IOS press

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @Alan Munn, I turn my comment into an answer.

- `times` This package change the text body font to `ptm`, sans serif to `phv` and typewriter font to `pcr`. These are the postscript fonts Times Roman (maybe Times New Roman, can't remember), Helvetica, and Courier, respectively. They are distributed with standard TeX distributions like TeXLive. If I remember correctly, these are fonts denoted by URW++. `times` does not touch the math fonts at all and the Helvetica and Courier are not properly scaled either.
- `mathptmx` This package change the default roman fonts to `ptm`, just as `times`. It does not change sans serif and typewriter fonts. In addition it change the math fonts to a virtual font `mathptmx`, which is basically Times Italic. Additional symbols and alphabets are borrowed from Computer Modern and RSFS.

Information of the above two packages can be found in detail from the documents `psnfss2e.pdf` and `psfonts.pdf`, distributed with TeXLive, etc.

- `mathtime` This package is for use with the commercial font MathTime and MathTime Plus, distributed by Y&Y (now defunct). It changes the text fonts the same as `times`. (My comment seems not to be entirely correct. After check the code of the package, it looks like it does change text fonts, including, rm, sf and tt). However this is now deprecated. But it is widely used in industry, including Springer and Elsevier. And quite popular in academic before, just like Y&Y. So it is very possible that you got a document still use it.
- `mtpro2`. This package is for use with the commercial font MathTime Professional 2, distributed by [PCTeX](http://www.pctex.com/). It has much improvement over MathTime. This package does not set any text fonts. It can be viewed as a successor to the MathTime. If you use `mtpro2`, it is better to set text font by `\def\rmdefault{ptm}`.

Loading two packages that change text fonts are usually okay. The latter will normally overwritten the first one. However math fonts is much more complicated. And I don't recommend one to load `mathptmx` and `mathtime` or `mtpro2` together. I don't have MathTime on my computer and I cannot check what will happen. But the limitations on math fonts are very likely to cause problem. (Mainly the limitations on number of math fonts family and other problems can be caused by math fonts setup commands like `\DeclareMathSymbol`.)

Answer (score 0):

The MathTime fonts are not part of standard LaTeX but have to be acquired separately (bought). You can find on ctan `mathtime.ins` and `.dtx` to install `mathtime.sty` if you have
the MathTime fonts.

Comment: You can use `\usepackage{lmodern}`or `\usepackage{fourier}`

Comment: @gpu Also, the `times` package is deprecated; you should use `mathptmx` instead.

Comment: @Alan if I understand correctly, to use Time like a normal font and with math fonts, it's necessary to call `mathptmx.sty`and 'mathtime.sty` ? Is `mathtime.sty` obsolete also ?

Comment: @Altermundus No, I don't think `mathtime.sty` is obsolete. So yes, you need to load both.  `mathtime` allows the math parts to come from the mathtime fonts instead of being cobbled together from other places (which is what `mathptmx` does).

Comment: @Altermundus `mathptmx` use `times` and a compatible designed math fonts for both text and math fonts. `mathtime` is a commercial font, which only set math fonts. What one can buy now is MathTime Pro 2, accompanied by package `mtpro2` together. In this sense, `mathtime` is obsolete. It is not recommended to load `mathptmx` and `mathtime` or `mtpro2`, instead, if one want to use MathTime fonts, use `\def\rmdefault` to change the text fonts is better.

Comment: @Yan can you turn your comment into an answer. (Clearly some of us are inadvertently propagating false information.)